# Conditional expectation of exponent to the power of BM, representation theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $T > 0$ and $M(t) = E[e^{W(T)}|F(t)]$ where $\{F(t) : t \geq 0\}$ is a natural filtration generated by W and $t \leq T$
I need to show that M(t) is a martingale and I also need to find a unique square integrable function $\phi$ for the representation
$M(t) = M(0) + \int_0^t \phi(s)dW(s)$

---

What I did:
for the martingale part I checked 3 conditions:

1. It does look adapted, doesn't depend on future values (not sure how to prove this rigorously)
2. Integrability: $E[|E[e^{W(T)}|F(t)]|] \leq (jensen) E[E[e^{|W(T)|}|F(t)]] = E[e^{|W(T)|}] = E[e^{\sqrt{T}*|\epsilon|}]  < \infty $ (I can just say that MGF is finite, right? $\epsilon$ is a standard normal random variable)
3. For any $s \leq t: E[M(t)|F(s)] = E[E[e^{W(T)}|F(t)]|F(s)] = E[E[e^{W(T)}|F(s)]|F(t)] = E[e^{W(T)}|F(s)] = M(s) $
   Thus $M(t)$ is a martingale

For the representation part:

$E[e^{W(T)}|F(t)] = M(0) + \int_0^t \phi(s)dW(s)$

Now, this is where I'm not sure if I'm doing it right:

$E[e^{W(T)}|F(t)] = E[e^{W(T) - W(t) + W(t)}|F(t)] = $ (take out what is known) $ e^{W(t)}*E[e^{W(T) - W(t)}|F(t)] = $ (independent increments) $ e^{W(t)}*E[e^{W(T)-W(t)}] = e^{W(t)}*e^{\frac{T-t}{2}} = e^{W(t) + 0.5(T - t)} $

$M(0) = e^{0.5T}$, so my representation turns into this:

$e^{W(t) - 0.5t} = \int_0^t \phi(s)dW(s)$

Now, I am going to use Ito on a function $f(x,t) = e^{x - 0.5t}$

$f_x = e^{x - 0.5t}$

$f_{xx} = e^{x - 0.5t}$

$f_t = -0.5e^{x - 0.5t}$

$d(f) = e^{x - 0.5t}dx - 0.5e^{x - 0.5t}dt + 0.5*e^{x - 0.5t}dt = e^{x - 0.5t}dx$

$e^{W(t) - 0.5t}  = 1 + \int_0^t e^{W(s)-0.5s}dW(s) = \int_0^t \frac{1}{W(t)} + e^{W(s) - 0.5s}dW(s)$

So my $\phi$ is $\frac{1}{W(t)} + e^{W(s) - 0.5s}$

I need to check that it is square-integrable, but for some reason I'm confused about the $\frac{1}{W(t)}$. Do I treat it as a constant and freely take out of expectation or ... maybe I made a mistake somewhere? 
I hope someone can give me a helping hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already applied Ito's lemma to find
$$
e^{W(T)-T/2}=1+\int_{0}^{T}e^{W(s)-s/2}dW(s).
$$
Next, note that
\begin{multline*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{T}e^{W(s)-s/2}dW(s)\mid\mathcal{F}(t)\right]=\int_{0}^{t}e^{W(s)-s/2}dW(s)+\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{t}^{T}e^{W(s)-s/2}dW(s)\mid\mathcal{F}(t)\right]\\=\int_{0}^{t}e^{W(s)-s/2}dW(s).
\end{multline*}
Therefore, applying conditional expectations to the first equation,
$$
e^{-T/2}M(t)=1+\int_{0}^{t}e^{W(s)-s/2}dW(s).
$$
Multiplying by $e^{T/2}$ yields the desired result.

Comment: So the answer will be $e^{\frac{T - s}{2} + W(s)}$. Man, what a silly oversight by me ... thank you very much. May I ask if the adaptivity and integrability for the martingale property can be explained in a more sensible way? This MGF of an absolute value seems quite non-trivial

Comment: I think the MGF approach is fine (there might be some minor mistakes in the argument but the basic idea is fine). As for the martingale property, try proving it from first principles. If you are still having trouble, I can spend more time on this in the future.

Comment: Nah, I figured out it already. Thank you very much. The absolute value should be dropped since exponent is always positive. Removes all the complications.